# GISC exercise 8.24 and 8.26: if-condition in result-form of cond not working as expected

Tags: common-lisp

Exercise 8.24 and 8.26 of David Touretzky's "A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation" state:

8.24: Write COUNT-DOWN, a function that counts down from n using list-consing recursion. (count 5) should produce the list (5 4 3 2 1).

8.26: Suppose we wanted to modify COUNT-DOWN so that the list it
constructs ends in zero. For example, (COUNT-DOWN 5) would produce (5 4 3 2 1 0). [...]

So I tried to combine the two exercises into a function `countdown` that takes a keyword argument `incl-zero`, like so:

```
(defun countdown (n &key (incl-zero nil))
  (cond
    ((zerop n) (if incl-zero '(0) nil))
    (t (cons n (countdown (1- n))))))

(countdown 5)
(countdown 5 :incl-zero t)
```

However both calls to countdown return `(5 4 3 2 1)`, so it seems like `:incl-zero t` does not reach the if-condition. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

omg I feel stupid.

```
(defun countdown (n &key (incl-zero nil))
  (cond
    ((zerop n) (if incl-zero '(0) nil))
    (t (cons n (countdown (1- n) :incl-zero incl-zero)))))

(countdown 5)
(countdown 5 :incl-zero t)
```

Fell prey to the recursion meme I guess..

Answer (score 3):

You noticed the error but note that when you have arguments that do not change from one call to another, you should probably define a local recursive function to pass only the arguments that *do* change. This is simpler to write and understand. Moreover, passing keyword arguments might come with a little bit of runtime overhead.

```
(defun countdown (n &key (incl-zero nil))
  (labels ((recurse (n)
             (cond
               ((zerop n) (if incl-zero '(0) nil))
               (t (cons n (recurse (1- n)))))))
    (recurse n)))
```